# Get cell value in MySQL query where date

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
-----------------------------
| id  | deadline   | Notify |
-----------------------------
| 1   | 2017-06-16 | 4      | // true
| 2   | 2017-06-17 | 5      | // true
| 3   | 2017-06-18 | 5      | // false -> tomorrow
| 4   | 2017-06-19 | 6      | // false -> tomorrow
-----------------------------
```

The notify column present the days before the deadline when a notification should be sent.

Using the following query gives me the record for all the deadlines in 5 days

```
SELECT * FROM `issues` WHERE deadline = DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

How can I use the cell information of the same row? So that, in this example, I get the rows #1 and #2?

Comment: Note that deadline is a DATE, so DATE() is redundant. Likewise, CURDATE() is DATE(NOW())

Comment: @Strawberry Good information, thanks!

Comment: @Strawberry you are great. i have been seeing your are providing good soluitons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM issues
WHERE deadline - INTERVAL Notify DAY <= NOW()
```

The above query returns rows `1, 2`. If you want to return all rows with a `true, false` flag then you can try the following query:

```
SELECT *,
       IF(deadline - INTERVAL Notify DAY <= NOW(), true, false) AS flag
FROM issues
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/EZA26069)

Comment: Thank you, didn't know I could use column name there.

Answer (score 0):

The deadline - current date gives the number of days before expiring. So try

```
SELECT * FROM `issues` WHERE DATE(deadline) - DATE(NOW()) <= 5
```